# How to get correct value back from AsyncTask through an Activity class and a normal class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I have 3 simplified classes as follow:

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity implements SomeTask.OnAsyncRequestComplete {
    SomeTask someTask;
    String someString = ""; //checkpoint 1

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new SomeDialog(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void asyncResponseSomeTask(String response) {
        someString = someTask.someString; //checkpoint 4
    }
}
```

SomeDialog.java

```
public class SomeDialog {
    public SomeDialog(Context context){
        SomeTask someTask = new SomeTask(context);
        someTask.execute("");
    }
}
```

SomeTask.java

```
public class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String someString;
    OnAsyncRequestComplete caller;
    Context context;

    public SomeTask(Context a) {    
        caller = (OnAsyncRequestComplete) a;
        context = a;
    }

    public String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        doSomething();
        return "";
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        //does some stuff here and gets value from a webpage
        someString = "some string"; //checkpoint 2
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String response) {
        //checkpoint 3
        caller.asyncResponseSomeTask(response);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Main` calls `SomeDialog` and passes its context along. `SomeDialog` calls and executes `SomeTask`, whose `onPostExecute` gets returned back to `Main`.

I'm interested in getting the value of `someString` from `SomeTask` back to `Main`.

Checking the value of `someString` along its checkpoints, I find:

- checkpoint 1: `someString` is empty ("")
- checkpoint 2: `someString` is not empty ("some string")
- checkpoint 3: `someString` is not empty ("some string")
- checkpoint 4: `someString` is empty ("")

So, it appears to me that `SomeTask` is doing its job perfectly fine (communicates with the webpage and gets the right data back). In `onPostExecute`, it even has the right value. Nevertheless, something happens as `Main` calls its `asyncResponseSomeTask` method and the value is lost. Maybe `Main` isn't waiting for `SomeTask` to finish before it finishes itself? But if that were the case, then I would get checkpoint 4's value before 2 or 3 (since communicating with the website does take some time), which I don't see happening.

My question is: How do I get `someString`'s correct value in `Main`?

I'm not particularly interested in calling `SomeTask` from `Main` (and not through `SomeDialog`). I know that doing that does work and yields the correct result, but I'm wondering about how to do it in this manner.

Comment: I don't think this code would compile. Class name is `SomeTask` and constructor is `City`? Where have you defined `caller`?

Comment: My bad. That's a typo. Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `Main#asyncResponseTask` be doing `someString = response`?

Comment: And `doInBackground()` should return `someString`?

Comment: Also you might want to change `someString = someTask.someString;` to `someString = response;`. I don't see `someTask` getting initialized anywhere in Main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting empty String because you are returning empty String from `doInBackground()` which gets as input to `onPostExecute()` and finally in the callback `asyncResponseSomeTask()`.

> How do I get someString's correct value in Main?

```
public String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    return doSomething();
}

private String doSomething() {
    //does some stuff here and gets value from a webpage
    someString = "some string"; //checkpoint 2
    return someString;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind this. I feel like, since `SomeTask`'s `someString` is already a global value, editing it in `doSomething()` would edit it globally (which makes sense because it has the correct value at checkpoints 2 AND 3).

Comment: Then you should do `caller.asyncResponseSomeTask(someString);` from `onPostExecute`

Comment: Whatever you return from `doInBackground()` will be argument for method `onPostExecute()` which is empty String in your case.

Comment: Thank you. This has helped a lot.